# IIS asking for windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I deployed my asp.net app in iis 7 and allow anonymous users but when I enter username and password it asks for windows authentication multiple times. When I cancel the dialog box again n again then it redirects me to the homepage. Please tell how to solve it

Comment: Have you enabled anonymous users in web.config? And also have you enabled anonymous authentication in the IIS site's authentication section?

Comment: Please tell me how to enable this things

Comment: Are you using just IE or a mix of browsers?

Comment: Using IE browser and it is showing same behaviour on other browsers also.

Comment: Does it happen to multiple users?  Is the test user's password expired?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to bypass any proxies between the systems? I've had similar problems myself because the proxy didn't pass through authentication info

Comment: this could be a comment

Comment: don't have enougth reputation to comment

Answer (score 0):

In web.config of your site there should be anonymous users allowed:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

In addition Anonymous authentication must be enabled for your web site on IIS. To enable it select your site in IIS and on the right find Authentification icon. Open it, enable anonymous authentication and disable windows authentification.

Comment: Setting anonymous in IIS should also modify the web.config.